# Antimalware for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: security, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I understand that there is way to enable Antimalware for Azure VM like below:

[image: Antimalware]

But I don't see such option when creating a Cloud Service.
There is a worker role running on Azure Cloud Service. The organization has a security rule of having Antimalware on the machines.
Does a Cloud Service by default contain antimalware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Wish Microsoft were better at documenting their stuff. It seems that AntiMalware extension is also avialable for Cloud Services, not only Virtual Machines. But this can only be understood from [the PowerShell reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn771715.aspx). And [another resource entirely for Extensions on Cloud Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn169558.aspx).

A valid and working PowerShell Script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/astaykov/c68bc86f43ba28163312):

```
Add-AzureAccount
# use Select-AzureSubscription in case your account has more than one 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'PUT HERE YOUR SUBSCRIPTION'
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $XmlConfig = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument 
# load the Antimalware extension configuration from external XML file
# The content of the XML needs to be:
# <AntimalwareConfig><AntimalwareEnabled>true</AntimalwareEnabled></AntimalwareConfig>
# ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn771718
$XmlConfig.load('D:\tmp\AntiMalware.config')
Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension -ServiceName "PUT HERE THE CLOUD SERVICE NAME" -AntimalwareConfiguration $XmlConfig
```

Comment: Did u keep the above power shell script has startup task and executed it

Comment: can you rephrase your question? I can't understand what you are asking.